# How to split Datetime into date and time separately in python

Tags: python

I have a `datetime` format of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` in one line and I want to split date and time in separate columns can any one help

```
df_train['Time1'] = df_train['server_time'].apply(lambda x : x.split(' ')[1])
```

when I apply this code I'm getting an error as `"list index out of range"`

Comment: Try `df_train['server_time'].str.split(' ', expand=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you.

```
df_train['date'] = [d.date() for d in df_train['server_time']]
df_train['time'] = [d.time() for d in df_train['server_time']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date and time from datetime.date and datetime.time:

```
import datetime as dt

df_train['Date'] = df_train['server_time'].dt.date
df_train['Time'] = df_train['server_time'].dt.time
```